# Equation - Keep number on same line as equation

Tags: equations

I have these equations and their numbers are on the same line.

```
\begin{equation}
    i_t = \sigma(W_{xi} * X_t + W_ {hi} * H_{t-1} + W_{ci} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f_t = \sigma(W_{xf} * X_t + W_ {hf} * H_{t-1} + W_{cf} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    C_t = f_t \circ C_{t-1} + i_t \circ \textnormal{tanh}(W_{xc} * X_t + W_{hc} * H_{t-1} + b_c)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    o_t = \sigma(W_{xo} * X_t + W_ {ho} * H_{t-1} + W_{co} \circ C_{t} + b_o)
\end{equation}
```

[image]

But doing this formatting causes the number to not be on the same line. How can I force the number to be on the same line ?

```
\begin{align}
  i_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xi}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hi}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{ci}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
  f_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xf}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hf}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{cf}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)\\
  C_t &= f_t \circ C_{t-1} + i_t \circ \text{tanh}(W_{\!\textit{xc}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{hc}} * H_{t-1} + b_c)\\
  o_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xo}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{ho}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{co}} \circ C_{t} + b_o)
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, yourthird equation is too wide to fit into the textwidth to it gets pushed to the next line. Keeping it in the same line as the equation would cause an overlap.

Comment: Please make your examples compilable. Since there are neither the documentclass nor other relevant settings (size of margins,...) given, the output can not be reproduced.

Comment: with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
i_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xi}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hi}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{ci}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
f_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xf}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hf}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{cf}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)\\
C_t &= f_t \circ C_{t-1} + i_t \circ \text{tanh}(W_{\!\textit{xc}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{hc}} * H_{t-1} + b_c)\\
o_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xo}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{ho}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{co}} \circ C_{t} + b_o)
\end{align}
\end{document}
` I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Some of the equations are just too long. If the * is ordinary multiplication (even of matrices or functions) and not, say, a convolution,  then you could just omit it and shorten everything, perhaps enough. Or split the few long equations over two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can find a way to simplify and shorten the material on the right-hand side of equation (3), the best solution consists of introducing a deliberate line-break in in that material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
\newcommand\vn[1]{\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  i_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\vn{xi}} * X_t + W_{\vn{hi}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\vn{ci}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
  f_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\vn{xf}} * X_t + W_{\vn{hf}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\vn{cf}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_{\vn{f}})\\
  C_t &= f_t \circ C_{t-1} \notag \\
      &\qquad + i_t \circ \text{tanh}(W_{\!\vn{xc}} * X_t + W_{\vn{hc}} * H_{t-1} + b_c)\\
  o_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\vn{xo}} * X_t + W_{\vn{ho}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\vn{co}} \circ C_{t} + b_o)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```