# Can I get some help cleaning up my equations?

Tags: equations

Hi I am new to latex and need help cleaning up my equations. This is what I have.

[image]

- I need equation (3) to be aligned with the number (3)
- Equations (5) and (6) to be centered and aligned only with each other

Here is the mwe. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/icml-2019-submission-template/vkqjjvzjvhdc

```
%%%%%%%% ICML 2019 EXAMPLE LATEX SUBMISSION FILE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{article}

% Recommended, but optional, packages for figures and better typesetting:
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for professional tables
\usepackage{amsmath}

% hyperref makes hyperlinks in the resulting PDF.
% If your build breaks (sometimes temporarily if a hyperlink spans a page)
% please comment out the following usepackage line and replace
% \usepackage{icml2019} with \usepackage[nohyperref]{icml2019} above.
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Attempt to make hyperref and algorithmic work together better:
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}

% Use the following line for the initial blind version submitted for review:
\usepackage{icml2019}

% If accepted, instead use the following line for the camera-ready submission:
%\usepackage[accepted]{icml2019}

% The \icmltitle you define below is probably too long as a header.
% Therefore, a short form for the running title is supplied here:
\icmltitlerunning{Submission and Formatting Instructions for ICML 2019}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\icmltitle{Submission and Formatting Instructions for \\
           International Conference on Machine Learning (ICML 2019)}

% It is OKAY to include author information, even for blind
% submissions: the style file will automatically remove it for you
% unless you've provided the [accepted] option to the icml2019
% package.

% List of affiliations: The first argument should be a (short)
% identifier you will use later to specify author affiliations
% Academic affiliations should list Department, University, City, Region, Country
% Industry affiliations should list Company, City, Region, Country

% You can specify symbols, otherwise they are numbered in order.
% Ideally, you should not use this facility. Affiliations will be numbered
% in order of appearance and this is the preferred way.
\icmlsetsymbol{equal}{*}

\begin{icmlauthorlist}
\icmlauthor{Aeiau Zzzz}{equal,to}
\icmlauthor{Bauiu C.~Yyyy}{equal,to,goo}
\icmlauthor{Cieua Vvvvv}{goo}
\icmlauthor{Iaesut Saoeu}{ed}
\icmlauthor{Fiuea Rrrr}{to}
\icmlauthor{Tateu H.~Yasehe}{ed,to,goo}
\icmlauthor{Aaoeu Iasoh}{goo}
\icmlauthor{Buiui Eueu}{ed}
\icmlauthor{Aeuia Zzzz}{ed}
\icmlauthor{Bieea C.~Yyyy}{to,goo}
\icmlauthor{Teoau Xxxx}{ed}
\icmlauthor{Eee Pppp}{ed}
\end{icmlauthorlist}

\icmlaffiliation{to}{Department of Computation, University of Torontoland, Torontoland, Canada}
\icmlaffiliation{goo}{Googol ShallowMind, New London, Michigan, USA}
\icmlaffiliation{ed}{School of Computation, University of Edenborrow, Edenborrow, United Kingdom}

\icmlcorrespondingauthor{Cieua Vvvvv}{c.vvvvv@googol.com}
\icmlcorrespondingauthor{Eee Pppp}{ep@eden.co.uk}

% You may provide any keywords that you
% find helpful for describing your paper; these are used to populate
% the "keywords" metadata in the PDF but will not be shown in the document
\icmlkeywords{Machine Learning, ICML}

\vskip 0.3in
]

% this must go after the closing bracket ] following \twocolumn[ ...

% This command actually creates the footnote in the first column
% listing the affiliations and the copyright notice.
% The command takes one argument, which is text to display at the start of the footnote.
% The \icmlEqualContribution command is standard text for equal contribution.
% Remove it (just {}) if you do not need this facility.

%\printAffiliationsAndNotice{}  % leave blank if no need to mention equal contribution
\printAffiliationsAndNotice{\icmlEqualContribution} % otherwise use the standard text.

\begin{abstract}
This document provides a basic paper template and submission guidelines.
Abstracts must be a single paragraph, ideally between 4--6 sentences long.
Gross violations will trigger corrections at the camera-ready phase.
\end{abstract}

\section{Electronic Submission}
\label{submission}

\small
\begin{align}
  \hspace*{-0.2cm} i_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xi}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hi}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{ci}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
  \hspace*{-0.2cm} f_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xf}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hf}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{cf}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)\\
  \hspace*{-0.2cm} C_t &= f_t \circ C_{t-1} + i_t \circ \tanh(W_{\!\textit{xc}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{hc}} * H_{t-1} + b_c)\\
  \hspace*{-0.2cm} o_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xo}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{ho}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{co}} \circ C_{t} + b_o)\\
  S_t &= o_t \circ \textnormal{tanh}(C_t)\\
  H_{t,ij} &= \frac{||S_{t,ij}^2||}{1 + ||S_{t,ij}^2||} \frac{S_{t,ij}}{||S_{t,ij}||}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Thanks leandriis for the answer. But why does overleaf highlight everything as if its an error? This happens when I nest align inside of gather

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the `icml2019` package available online somewhere?

Comment: @Mico hello, yes if you open the link, click open as template, then you will see the package. You can also directly copy paste the mwe after opening as template

Comment: Try to put one `\hspace{2cm}` at the end of the first equation and delete the other `\hspace` macros. As for the alignment of the two lower equations: would it be a solution to just put these to into another `align` environment? — Off topic: you can write `\tanh` instead of `\textnormal{tanh}` and you could omit the ˚\textit` macros, I think.

Comment: I have tried putting the other 2 equations into another align environment but the spacing between the two environments become too large and putting a negative vspace places the equation on top of one another, no matter the value I put https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518683/vspace-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1311703_518683

Comment: Questions about Overleaf-specific behavior should be addressed to the Overleaf helpdesk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combining the comments and answers to your previous three questions I end up with the following MWE. In it, I have used two `align` environments inside of a `gather` environment, [as I recommended earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518683/vspace-not-working#comment1311703_518683). For the first variant, I have kept the `\small` font size as well as the `\hspace*` commands, while in the second example, I have split up the third equation into two lines in order to prevent the equation number from shifting downwards. This was [already recommended by Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518671/134144).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{icml2019}

\begin{document}

\section{Electronic Submission}
\label{submission}

\small
\begin{gather}
  \begin{align}
    \hspace*{-0.2cm} i_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xi}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hi}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{ci}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
    \hspace*{-0.2cm} f_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xf}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hf}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{cf}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)\\
    \hspace*{-0.2cm} C_t &= f_t \circ C_{t-1} + i_t \circ \tanh(W_{\!\textit{xc}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{hc}} * H_{t-1} + b_c)\\
    \hspace*{-0.2cm} o_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xo}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{ho}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{co}} \circ C_{t} + b_o)
  \end{align}\\
  \begin{align}
    S_t &= o_t \circ \tanh(C_t)\\
    H_{t,ij} &= \frac{||S_{t,ij}^2||}{1 + ||S_{t,ij}^2||} \frac{S_{t,ij}}{||S_{t,ij}||}
  \end{align}
\end{gather}
\normalsize

\begin{gather}
  \begin{align}
     i_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xi}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hi}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{ci}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
     f_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xf}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hf}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{cf}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)\\
     C_t &= f_t \circ C_{t-1} \notag\\
         &+ i_t \circ \tanh(W_{\!\textit{xc}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{hc}} * H_{t-1} + b_c)\\
     o_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xo}} * X_t + W_{\!\textit{ho}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{co}} \circ C_{t} + b_o)
  \end{align}\\
  \begin{align}
    S_t &= o_t \circ \tanh(C_t)\\
    H_{t,ij} &= \frac{||S_{t,ij}^2||}{1 + ||S_{t,ij}^2||} \frac{S_{t,ij}}{||S_{t,ij}||}
  \end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much! That works! But may I ask why overleaf highlights the entire block with the message as if its an error even though its compilable? I have added this to my original post.

Answer (score 4):

I would also use a pair of `align` environments inside a `gather` environment. I would *not* use the `\hspace*{-0.2cm}`, though. To make all six equations fit, I would reset the values of `thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip`, and `\thickmuskip`. These parameters govern the amount of whitespace that's inserted on each side of math operators.

Oh, and I would not write `||`, i.e., two consecutive `|` symbols to create the "norm" delimiter. Instead, use either `\lVert` and `\rVert` or, more elegantly, load the `mathtools` package and create a macro called `\norm` with variable-size fences.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure} % this package is deprecated
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{mathtools} % superset of 'amsmath' package
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

\newcommand\vn[1]{\textit{#1}} % how to typeset variable names

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}

\usepackage{icml2019}

\begin{document}

\section{Electronic Submission}
\label{submission}

\begingroup  %localize the scope of the following instructions
\small
\thickmuskip=2.5mu % choose values half as large as the defaults
\medmuskip=2mu
\thinmuskip=1.5mu
\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
  i_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\vn{xi}} * X_t + 
                W_{\vn{hi}} * H_{t-1} + 
                W_{\!\vn{ci}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
  f_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\vn{xf}} * X_t + 
                W_{\vn{hf}} * H_{t-1} + 
                W_{\!\vn{cf}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_{\vn{f}})\\
  C_t &= f_t \circ C_{t-1} + i_t \circ 
         \tanh(W_{\!\vn{xc}} * X_t + 
         W_{\!\vn{hc}} * H_{t-1} + b_c)\\
  o_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\vn{xo}} * X_t + 
                W_{\!\vn{ho}} * H_{t-1} + 
                W_{\!\vn{co}} \circ C_{t} + b_o)
\end{align}\\
\begin{align}
  S_t      &= o_t \circ \tanh(C_t)\\
  H_{t,ij} &= \frac{\norm{S_{t,ij}^2}}{1+\norm{S_{t,ij}^2}} 
              \frac{S_{t,ij}}{\norm{S_{t,ij}}}
\end{align}
\end{gather}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```